# Functions in ARM

Tags: assembly, arm

I am new to ARM programming and I do not know which registers to push to the stack at the beginning of my function. Also, where would I find the parameters passed into the function? Thanks!

Comment: Consult the calling convention documentation, or [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#ARM_.28A32.29) for a quick overview.

Comment: You should try with some C functions and disassemble those function to get an idea on how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just try it the tools are easy to come by, they conform with the calling convention, makes it easier to compare what you see with the language of the convention.

```
extern unsigned int more_fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b );
unsigned int fun0 ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    return(more_fun(a+1,b+2)+3);
}
```

build, disassemble, and examine (better to disassemble than to try to wade through the compiler generated assembly language, but if you put -save-temps on the gcc command line you will get both.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O2 -c so.c -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   e2811002    add r1, r1, #2
   8:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
   c:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <more_fun>
  10:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
  14:   e2800003    add r0, r0, #3
  18:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

so of course you have to save the return address if you are calling another function.  and this shows r0 is the first parameter r1 the second and r0 the register the return value is in.  whats with r4?  that is because the convention wants the stack 64 bit aligned so an even number of registers pushed or popped before calling or returning (the compiler does not keep the stack 64 bit aligned at all times, BTW).

```
extern unsigned int more_fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b );
unsigned int fun0 ( unsigned int a, unsigned long long b )
{
    return(more_fun(a+1,b+2)+3);
}
```

32 bit quanities are easy, 64 bit they do things like this

```
00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   e2821002    add r1, r2, #2
   8:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
   c:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <more_fun>
  10:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
  14:   e2800003    add r0, r0, #3
  18:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

first parameter takes r0, second is 64 bits so they skip r1 and use r2/r3, but since this is being trimmed from 64 bits to 32 bits to make the call to the next function they just use r2.  being a 32 bit parameter to the next function, needs to be in r1, thus the move.

```
extern unsigned int more_fun ( unsigned int a, unsigned long long b );
unsigned int fun0 ( unsigned int a, unsigned long long b )
{
    return(more_fun(a+1,b+2)+3);
}

00000000 <fun0>:
   0:   e2922002    adds    r2, r2, #2
   4:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   8:   e2a33000    adc r3, r3, #0
   c:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
  10:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <more_fun>
  14:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
  18:   e2800003    add r0, r0, #3
  1c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

r0-r3 are used for the first parameters until they are consumed, after that it uses the stack for parameters.  Easy as shown to prototype the function to figure out what the compiler you are mating up with is doing, then working from that as well as looking at the spec to see why the compiler is doing what it is doing.